# Do I need a divorce certificate (talaq nama) to prove I am divorced?

Tags: talaq

My ex husband divorced me 5 years ago verbally, in front of my father and brother. Do I need a talaq nama to prove I am divorced?

Comment: Need it for what? Modern governments would probably require you to have documentation and registration of your divorce for administrative purposes. Islamically there is no need for a written document to make the divorce valid.